# SSH over Socks proxy without username or password

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunneling, backtrack, socks

I have a list of SOCKS proxy servers from [this](http://spys.ru/en/socks-proxy-list/) site.

I've read about creating a dynamic tunnels with `ssh -D` and to be honest i've tried that already. Unfortunately for some reason I cannot connect to any of the proxy servers from the list.

I am using `OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k` on BackTrack.
If anyone would be willing to help or point to step by step guide which will work for me I would be very grateful.

What I want to achieve is Connect from Machine `A` through ssh tunnel on Machine `B` to Machine `C`. Lets say sshd on Machine `C` is listening on port 21 and Machine `B` proxy is listening on port 1080.

Additional Question:

I would also like to create a tunnel to socks proxy server which would allow me to setup localhost:8080 in firefox as a proxy and allow me to browse the net from the Machine `B` with Machine `B` IP address.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Am I right to assume that "Machine `B`" is supposed to be from that list?

Comment: I'm trying to use a server in the middle as a jump proxy to connect to third machine. the B machine is from the list - correct. I would also like to create a tunnel to socks proxy server which would allow me to setup localhost:8080 in firefox as a proxy and allow me  to browse the net from the Machine B with Machine B IP address.

Comment: Why are you running ssh on port 21?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a socks client, or a ssh client that understand socks. `-D` is for ssh to be a socks server/proxy.

You could use ssh under `tsocks`, or another SOCKS wrapper. Or use ssh's ProxyCommand in conjunction with `socat` or `nc -X`:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - socks:B:%h:21,socksport=1080' C
```

To have a HTTP proxy that uses the SOCKS server to send HTTP requests, you can run a small proxy (like `tinyproxy`) under tsocks.

Note that not all applications play nicely with `tsocks` or any similar wrapper that relies on `LD_PRELOAD`, but `tinyproxy` does.

Also note that you may have issues with domain name resolution (depending on whether you want the names to be resolved on either side of the tunnel). `tsocks` doesn't work well for resolving names remotely. The only way it can work is when your nameserver (in `/etc/resolv.conf`) is reachable from the other end and you're using TCP for domain resolution (which `tsocks` can attempt to enforce but generally fails in my experience). `socksify` from `dante`'s SOCKS client/server works better in that instance as it also wraps resolving functions and can also use a nice little trick to fake name resolution so that SOCKS by-name connections can be used.

Comment: YEY ! It works `ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - socks:218.62.97.105:HOST_B:21,socksport=1080' C`. Thats really great. Thank you. Would you be able to suggest a command to create a tunnel with this socks proxy that i could setup in firefox as a local web proxy? Im not sure if this can work : Firefox + local port tunnel -> socks tunnel Machine B -> HTTP Server. If it is possible and you know how to do this, please share and i promise you +100 :) for that. If it is impossible i will still give +50 for the answer above.

Comment: Firefox supports socks directly (see proxy options in advanced, network settings)

Comment: Ok. Maybe i misguided you by suggesting Firefox. Lets say CURL - and i want to connect via local proxy so i can automate in bash script the tunnel creation.

Comment: Well, curl supports SOCKS as well. So you'd like to turn a socks proxy into an HTTP proxy? Then you can run an HTTP proxy server (like `tinyproxy`) under `tsocks`

Comment: Ok. tsocks seems to be exactly what i need. prize in 2 days as promissed. Thank you very much. :)